# Spoj - Horrible using segment trees

Tags: c++, algorithm, segment-tree

I'm getting incorrect results for problem [HORRIBLE](http://www.spoj.com/problems/HORRIBLE/)

Here is my code : 
http://ideone.com/1Yb3yp

```
node query(int root,int l_most,int r_most,int l,int r)
{
  if(l_most >= l && r_most <= r)
    return tree[root];
  int l_child = (root<<1) , r_child = l_child + 1,mid = (l_most + r_most )>>1;
  node left=node(),right = node();
  if(l<=mid)
    left = query(l_child,l_most,mid,l,r);
  if(r>mid)
    right = query(r_child,mid+1,r_most,l,r);;
  node temp = node();
  temp.merge(left,right);
  return temp;
}
```

Comment: What do you get and what were you expecting? And post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to let us check how the program behaves.

Comment: i think the update isn't working properly.. expecting `80
508`

Comment: @AdriC.S.  couldn't figure out where i went wrong,..void create is used for update..

Comment: @wen_dy you want a correct solution? I got AC using BIT...or do you want someone to help you debug your segment tree code?